# 'I don't get no money' - how is this correct

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I was chatting with a friend when he said 'I don't get no money' - he was referring to some work he was doing. This usage of language confused me. I have come across phrases like this in movies and books too, but never quite understood it. How is 'I don't get no money' equivalent to 'I don't get any money'. I'm sorry if my question is phrased incorrectly. I'm not sure what tags to use either so edits would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, venkat. Please go through the previous posts. There's a wealth of information in here and more than one instance of this in the previous questions already answered.

Comment: It's non-standard (for  'I don't get any money' as you guess). If your friend's use of the expression surprised you, he was probably using it deliberately quirkily.

Comment: It's a double negative.  Rather than interpreting it literally, you should read the two negatives in the same sentence as reinforcing each other.

Comment: It's what's called [_Negative Concord,_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) a situation in which extra negatives reinforce earlier ones, as @SimonBarker points out. This is the norm in languages like Spanish (_No tengo nada_, 'I don't have anything', literally 'I don't have nothing'). Negative concord negatives don't cancel out like logical negatives sometimes do. English uses [Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) items like _anything,_ instead of another negative.